# Xamarin Forms - removing a child element from a StackLayout in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In the code-behind of a XAML page I'm checking whether a text field from my model is null, if not I update a labels text property with the field, if it is null I want to completely remove it from the XAML.

At first I tried to set the IsVisible to false and the HeightRequest to 0, but I could still see the space in the stackLayout where the label would have been, so I tried removing inner stack that contains the label from the main stack

```
TopStack.Children.Remove(addressStack);
```

But again I can still see a space where the removed stack would have been.

I there a way to remove the inner stack completely, including the space it would have occupied?

Comment: You probably need to call the `InvalidateMeasure` after removal

Comment: Did you try to call `ParentStack.ForceLayout()` after set `ParentStack.Children[X].IsVisible = false;`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `theStack.Children.Remove(textField);` to remove the element from the stack.

If you know the position of the element in the stack, you can use the remove at

```
  theStack.Children.RemoveAt(positionInStack);
```

If you want to remove the inner stack, which is a child to the outer stack and a parent to the text field, use the

```
outerStack.Children.Remove(textField.parent);
```

I hope this information will help you!